# cannot open source file "d3dx10.h"

Tags: visual-studio-2010

i need to know how to get VS2010 to recognise my directx file which is producing the error (see question title).

Im pretty sure i need to add the line:
"C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Directx SDK(June 2010)\Include

but im not entirely sure how to do this in 2010, so could someone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Top Google search result for "visual studio includes 2010"
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vcgeneral/thread/a494abb8-3561-4ebe-9eb0-6f644a679862

Comment: that was too confusing for me mate. sorry :( not a c++ programmer.

Answer (score 5):

In either Visual Studio 2010 or In VS C++ 2010 Express. The easiest way to do this without the overhead of preprocessor macros or long conviluted #include directives is simply this.

1st: use the standard #include  and/or #include

2nd: MS changed the location to setting the include files and libraries from Tools to an easier location. This change from 2008 to 2010 now is project dependent vs. Changing The Complete IDE.
So to the solution. Once you have your project started. And if you get the compile error: Can not open *.* no such file found. In your Solution Explorer there is about a 3-4 steps and you are done.
     1. Right Click on the Project (not the Solution) and Select Properties.
     2. In the left hand pane Select Configuration Properties->C/C++->General
     3. In the right hand side you will see (Additional Include Directories) to the right of this
        is where you want to add the path to your current DirectX SDK include directory
     4. Click apply and you are done!

Answer (score 1):

I am not a c++ programmer but this worked fine for me to get through my book.

```
#include "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\D3DX10.h"
```